# javascript infinite scrolling forward

Tags: javascript, html, user-experience

I am working on an infinite implementation.  At the moment, I am able to scroll down and the code does what it is supposed to do with this check:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300) {
  //do stuff
}
```

I also need to **do stuff** when I go forward.  The problem I have is that when the page first loads, the scroll bar is at the top of the page, is there an event or a way of knowing the user is scrolling up when the page first loads?

At the moment, the user has to scroll down and then up to trigger the event.

Comment: You should post some code, but you could try to scroll the screen at load, first down 1px and then up 1px.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i used

```
    window.onload = loadSubPage;
```

Hope it's what you are looking for :)